# Duration cannot be resolved or is not a field in WebDriverwait in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, fluentwait

I am trying to interact with a calendar on a webpage, so I am using WebDriver wait.

Below is the method:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.className("calendar")));
```

Is something wrong here?
The errors are shown as:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Duration cannot be resolved or is not a field
    - Syntax error on token ",", . expected
    - The constructor WebDriverWait(WebDriver, Duration) is 
     undefined
```

what is wrong here?

Comment: Have you imported  Duration class from 'java.time.Duration'?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the Duration issue :

```
import java.time.Duration;
```

import this at the top, "Duration" got resolved it worked for me.